# UISlider sticking at the second time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uislider

Hi i have a uislider that changes the images in uiimageview.At first time it works great there is no delay . But when i click the button to publish (there is a modal view that opens) and close the modal view (this is the second time) the uiimageview delays that shown the images.i cant find why it gets slower:(

```
-(IBAction)sliderSlide:(UISlider *)aSlider {

float f=slider.value;
NSString *show=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f %%",f];
label2.text=show;
NSString *show1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f",f];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Smiley_000%@.png", show1]];

float slid=slider.value;
if(slid>99)
{
    [imageView1 setHidden:NO];
    [imageView2 setHidden:YES];
    NSString *fullpath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/Smiley_00099.png"];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullpath];
    secondarray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:  
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rays_00000.png"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rays_00001.png"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rays_00002.png"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rays_00003.png"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rays_00004.png"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rays_00005.png"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rays_00006.png"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rays_00007.png"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rays_00008.png"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rays_00009.png"],
                 nil];

    imageView1.animationImages = secondarray;        
    // How many seconds it should take to go through all images one time.
    imageView1.animationDuration = 0.5;
    // How many times to repeat the animation (0 for indefinitely).
    imageView1.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    [imageView1 startAnimating];
}
else if (slid<1)
{
    [imageView2 setHidden:NO];
    [imageView1 setHidden:YES];
    NSString *fullpath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/Smiley_0000.png"];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullpath];
    firstarray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:  
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Teardrop_00000.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Teardrop_00001.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Teardrop_00002.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Teardrop_00003.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Teardrop_00004.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Teardrop_00005.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Teardrop_00006.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Teardrop_00007.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Teardrop_00008.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Teardrop_00009.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Teardrop_00000.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Teardrop_00000.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Teardrop_00000.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Teardrop_00000.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Teardrop_00000.png"],
                         nil];


    imageView2.animationImages = firstarray;        
    // How many seconds it should take to go through all images one time.
    imageView2.animationDuration = 0.8;

    // How many times to repeat the animation (0 for indefinitely).
    imageView2.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    [imageView2 startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView2];
}
else 
{
    [imageView1 setHidden:YES];
    [imageView2 setHidden:YES];
    [imageView1 stopAnimating];
    [imageView2 stopAnimating];
}
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:slid forKey:@"slider"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

this is my code if u can see why performance decrease in the second time i slide the slider pls tell me

edit 1:

i cancel some animations and slider get back to its speed but now the pictures are sticking slider okey but pictures are slow then the first time.

Comment: This is quite a lot of code to be running in a slider callback. Remember, this delegate method can be called hundreds of times per second.

Comment: yes you are right but (as a noob)i can't define the arrays in global so those lines will be gone.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My alertview makes the application (slider and images) goes slower so i remove it and it work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I would say that your first step here to making this method more responsive is to remove all object allocations and unnecessary logic from this delegate method. The slider delegate method can be called over 100 times a second (if it is setup as continuous) and you should really be using it to only update ivars and perform minimal logic. This is most likely the root cause of your delays. As for why it is happening on the second time around, perhaps you are duplicating slider setup on your `viewWillAppear`, so after the modal, the delegate method is called twice as much.

Comment: thanks for tips mate i check i dont use wiewwillappear the slider is also iboutlet but i am trying to minimaze the code in the function i ll report to you if it is going to be faster asap

Comment: nop mate its still the same i clean most of the code but still the second time it sticking.

Comment: Then perhaps you can post the code where you setup your slider, also all slider related code.

Comment: mate ı found the problem its my alertview it makes the application goes slower :( i remove it and work perfectly thanks for everthing